# Notify service from notification

Tags: android

I´ve have a android service running in foreground and have the notification in the notification dropdown.

Right now the notification have a pending intent to start an activity, but i would like it to just notify the service to turn off itself.

Is there a way to notify a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent.setAction("com.your.package.STOP_SERVICE");
PendingIntent stopService = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
// set pending intent in your notification
```

In your service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if ("STOP_SERVICE".equals(action)) {
        // stop your service
    }
}
```

Obviously you should change class names and constants as appropriate.